# views related content block // show content with specific initial letter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

i have a content-type with this fields:

```
title field
starting letter // term reference -> stores term in vocab "starting letter"
car brand // term reference -> stores term in vocab "car brand"
car model // term reference -> stores term in vocab "car model"
Image field
```

i have created a view that hast the url: example.com/vehicles/audi (the term audi comes from the vocab "car brand" in views this looks like vehicles/%)

on this page with the url example.com/vehicles/audi i want to show a block that contains a list of other cars which name starts with the letter A like:

```
Acura
Alfa Romeo
AMC
Ascari
```

the same should be work with brand starting with B, C and so on. i need a contextual solution.

my problem and what i dont unterstand:
how do i set this thing up, because i dont have the term "A" in my url which i could filter with the contextual filter. i just have the term "audi". can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Set argument for second view using `hook_views_pre_view()`.

```
$view->set_arguments(array('A'));
```

Comment: thank your for your reply. i should mention that i havent used the views API yet. i copied the code $view->set_arguments(array('A')); in my view under context.filter / PHP contextual filter code but this doesnt work right now. comes the hook_views_pre_view() elsewere?

second thing is, as i understand this blockview will always filter for the term "A". what i need is if the url changes for expample to example.com/vehicles/bmw the filter argument should be the term "B" from the vocab.

Comment: Not enough space in comment, answering below

Answer (score 0):

I never use php in admin interface, in my opinion it's not right. Because later it's too difficult to remember where you place your custom logic... I advise you to create a custom module and place your code there.

As for your method, I guess PHP contextual filter requires returnable value. So let's try this:

```
$parent_view = views_get_page_view(); // Get vehicle view
$arg = $parent_view->args[0]; // Get vehicle view argument
$letter = $arg[0]; // First letter of argument
return drupal_strtoupper($letter);
```

Comment: ok i have found this. what u think of it?

'code'
$view->set_arguments(array_pop(explode('/',drupal_get_path_alias())));
$output = $view->preview();
print $output;
'code'

is this noob php?